# activity transitions from and to a position in android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-transitions

I'd like to animate to an activity from a position on the screen like a zoom-in animation. (please watch the video)

Many android home screen launchers have this functionality.

What I'd like to achieve is in this [video](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/video/upload/v1577908055/zoom.mp4).
The video shows two animations that are somewhat close to zoom-in and zoom-out animations. (Like scale in and scale out?)

For now, I'm doing something like this.

```java
// calculate width, height, left and top
...
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeClipRevealAnimation(view, left, top, width, height);
Bundle bundle = options.toBundle();
Intent intent = ...
context.startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

This clip-reveal animation is not a scale animation. It reveals the activity vertically and it looks completely different.

And also when the user returns from the activity I need to implement the reverse zoom out animation like in the video. I don't know how to proceed with this.

Note that I have no control over the target activity as it is some other app's launch activity, thus I won't be able to use any shared transitions.

My app will be a home screen launcher. So the user **will** eventually return to the home screen app if this is set as the default launcher.
How do I detect when the user comes back and how to show the animation?

The second animation slowed down. [video](https://res.cloudinary.com/rootworld/video/upload/v1577909843/secondAnim.mp4)

Comment: have you test with this overridePendingTransition();

Comment: How can I specify this animation in xml?

Comment: you should use it after startActivity() or finish() like this > overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2)